# Two parametric integral

Tags: definite-integrals

How to obtain the explicit formula of the following integral
$$\int\limits_0^1 {{t^{ - 1 - x}}\left( {{{\left( {1 + t} \right)}^{ - y}} - 1} \right)} dt,\;x,y \in \left( { - 1,1} \right).$$
It can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric function？

Comment: On first look it seems to me like one could probably transofrm the above in a Beta-type integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: $$\int_0^1t^{-1-x}\left((1+t)^{-y}-1\right)\ dt=B(-x,1-y)-\int_0^1t^{-1-x}\ dt=B(-x,1-y)+\frac1x$$